# How do i reload the page after the any of the link is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html, smarty

Link to Approve, Program, Disapprove and Validate, Everything works fine except that i want the page refreshed every time any of the button is clicked.

Below are the HTML and the JQuery.

```js
$(function(){
  var url = "sites/erp/ajaxify/airtime_order_actions.php";
  $(".order_action").click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   var action = $(this).attr('id');
   if(action !=""){
    $.post(url, {id:id,action:action}, function(response){
     var data = JSON.parse(response);
     if(data.code == 1){
      $(".hint").html(data.msg);
      setTimeout(function(){
       location.reload();
      }, 3000)
     }else{
      $(".hint").html(data.msg);
     }
    });
   }
   return false;
  });
 });
```

```html
<!--{/if}-->
    </td>
    <td class="ord-act">
     <a href="?p=dashboard&a=print_orders&k=<!--{$order->order_id}-->" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Print Order">
      <span class="label label-primary"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></span>
     </a>
     <!--{if $order->validated eq 0 && $order->recommended eq 0 && $order->approved eq 0}-->
      <a href="#" class="order_action" data-id="<!--{$order->order_id}-->" id="validate">
       <span class="label label-default">Validate</span>
      </a>
                        
     <!--{elseif $order->validated eq 1 && $order->recommended eq 0 && $order->approved eq 0}-->
      <a href="#" class="order_action" data-id="<!--{$order->order_id}-->" id="recommend">
       <span class="label label-warning">Recommend</span>
      </a>
     <!--{elseif $order->validated eq 1 && $order->recommended eq 1 && $order->approved eq 0}-->
      <a href="#" class="order_action" data-id="<!--{$order->order_id}-->" id="approve">
       <span class="label label-info">Approve</span>
      </a>
     <!--{elseif $order->validated eq 1 && $order->recommended eq 1 && $order->approved eq 1}-->
      <a href="#" class="order_action" data-id="<!--{$order->order_id}-->" id="program">
       <span class="label label-success">Program</span>
      </a>
     <!--{/if}-->
     <!--{if $order->approved eq 0}-->
     <a href="#" class="order_action" data-id="<!--{$order->order_id}-->" id="disapprove">
      <span class="label label-danger">Disapprove</span>
     </a>
     <!--{/if}-->
    </td>
   </tr>
  <!--{/foreach}-->
 </tbody>
</table>
<!--{else}-->
 <div class="well well-sm text-center col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
  <h4><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> No Pending Airtime</h4>
  <p>There are no airtime orders available for now.</p>
  <a href="?p=dashboard&a=airtime_orders" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Refresh</a>
 </div>
<!--{/if}-->
```

Please help out... i am not very much that good please
Please help out... i am not very much that good please

Comment: Add onclick attribute and set it to location reload (`location.reload();`)

Comment: set this window.location.reload();

Comment: If you're reloading the page on any click the AJAX request seems pretty much pointless.

Comment: "set this window.location.reload();" where exactly will be suitable for this on the script?

Answer (score 1):

Add an Onclick attribute on all Links and set it to `location.reload();` OR add an Event Listener and listen for `click` and then set it to perform `location.reload();`.

Or you could add `location.reload();` at the end of the code that process the click.

Note : `location.reload();` is JavaScript.

EDIT :
Thanks to the comment, I noticed that there's actually `location.reload()` function present. But it will be executed after 3000ms. Please ensure that 3000ms has passed. If nothing happens, check the Console for any error message.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.reload()` instead location.reload() to refresh/reload the current page

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  var url = "sites/erp/ajaxify/airtime_order_actions.php";
  $(".order_action").click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   var action = $(this).attr('id');
   if(action !=""){
    $.post(url, {id:id,action:action}, function(response){
     var data = JSON.parse(response);
     if(data.code == 1){
      $(".hint").html(data.msg);
      setTimeout(function(){
       location.reload();
      }, 3000)
     }else{
      $(".hint").html(data.msg);
     }
    });
   }
   return false;
  });
 });
```

```html
<!--{/if}-->
    </td>
    <td class="ord-act">
     <a href="?p=dashboard&a=print_orders&k=<!--{$order->order_id}-->" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Print Order">
      <span class="label label-primary"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></span>
     </a>
     <!--{if $order->validated eq 0 && $order->recommended eq 0 && $order->approved eq 0}-->
      <a href="#" class="order_action" data-id="<!--{$order->order_id}-->" id="validate">
       <span class="label label-default">Validate</span>
      </a>
                        
     <!--{elseif $order->validated eq 1 && $order->recommended eq 0 && $order->approved eq 0}-->
      <a href="#" class="order_action" data-id="<!--{$order->order_id}-->" id="recommend">
       <span class="label label-warning">Recommend</span>
      </a>
     <!--{elseif $order->validated eq 1 && $order->recommended eq 1 && $order->approved eq 0}-->
      <a href="#" class="order_action" data-id="<!--{$order->order_id}-->" id="approve">
       <span class="label label-info">Approve</span>
      </a>
     <!--{elseif $order->validated eq 1 && $order->recommended eq 1 && $order->approved eq 1}-->
      <a href="#" class="order_action" data-id="<!--{$order->order_id}-->" id="program">
       <span class="label label-success">Program</span>
      </a>
     <!--{/if}-->
     <!--{if $order->approved eq 0}-->
     <a href="#" class="order_action" data-id="<!--{$order->order_id}-->" id="disapprove">
      <span class="label label-danger">Disapprove</span>
     </a>
     <!--{/if}-->
    </td>
   </tr>
  <!--{/foreach}-->
 </tbody>
</table>
<!--{else}-->
 <div class="well well-sm text-center col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
  <h4><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> No Pending Airtime</h4>
  <p>There are no airtime orders available for now.</p>
  <a href="?p=dashboard&a=airtime_orders" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Refresh</a>
 </div>
<!--{/if}-->
```